# How to fetch data entered on the rows of datagrid view vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row, ssms, fetch

I have a datagridview that consists of 6 columns. How can I fetch the data entered in each row for each columns? I have to save it into the SQL Server, I have enable editing in the properties of the datagridview for the user to input something on each row. Help :(

Answer (score 0):

To read the entire data grid you can use following code

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
     // Your logic to add data in DataTable or any container
     // To save it in database 
 Next
```

Once have data you can send it across to save in SQL Server